# Does this sequence have a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assume there are 50 doors each numbered 1 to 50. Run the following algorithm:

1. Open every door.
2. For each door number divisible by 2, close that door.
3. For each door number divisible by 3, if the door is open, close it. If the door is closed, open it.
4. For each door number divisible by 4, if the door is open, close it. If the door is closed, open it.
5. For each door number divisible by 5, if the door is open, close it. If the door is closed, open it.

I did this and ended up with the following doors being open: 1 4 6 7 8 10 11 13 15 16 17 18 19 23 28 29 31 32 37 41 42 43 44 45 47 49 50.

If you extend this out to 200 doors, the following doors would be open: 1 4 6 7 8 10 11 13 15 16 17 18 19 23 28 29 31 32 37 41 42 43 44 45 47 49 50 52 53 54 56 59 60 61 64 66 67 68 70 71 73 75 76 77 78 79 83 88 89 91 92 97 101 102 103 104 105 107 109 110 112 113 114 116 119 120 121 124 126 127 128 130 131 133 135 136 137 138 139 143 148 149 151 152 157 161 162 163 164 165 167 169 170 172 173 174 176 179 180 181 184 186 187 188 190 191 193 195 196 197 198 199.

To explain the algorithm further, 200 is open in step 1, closed in step 2, open in step 4 and closed in step 5. Hopefully the algorithm makes sense.

The only pattern I can come up with is the following. If you subtract open door 'k' from open door 'k-1', this pattern is repeated: 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 4 5 1 2 1 5 4 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 3 1. This assumes the first door is 1 away from door 0. Not only is that sequence repeated, but that sequence is itself a palindrome.

My ultimate goal is to find some closed form for 'n' doors. Given 'n' doors and this algorithm, how many doors remain open? Does such a closed form exist and is there an easier way to describe the sequence other than what I've already described?

Comment: Thank you @David. This was likely the issue. This is not the well known problem of "then every 6th door, then every 7th and so on." It stops at 5.

Comment: @McClane400: Sorry, I thought that after $5$ you would continue with $6$, $7$, and so on.

Comment: All is well, I will delete my comments. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 3):

The final result depends on the value of $n$ modulo $60$.  Once you have calculated which doors of the first $60$ are open, the pattern will repeat.  For example, $20$ and $200$ differ by a multiple of $60$, and you have calculated that they both end up closed.

This is because $n$ is divisible by $2$ if and only if $n+60$ is divisible by $2$, and likewise for divisibility by $3,4$ and $5$.

Furthermore, these four conditions will not all be true if $60$ is replaced by any smaller number.

In your sequence of differences, note that the total of all the numbers is $60$.  This is, again, because the whole thing repeats after $60$ doors.  And it is palindromic because $n$ is divisible by $2$ if and only if $60-n$ is divisible by $2$, and likewise for $3,4,5$.

Comment: Yes, 60 is the first number divisible by 2, 3, 4 and 5 and therefore the repeating. I like that. However, is there a way to come up with the values of 1-59 without brute force?

Comment: This is a perfect answer for why the sequence repeats. Now my only question is: "why that particular sequence?" Maybe better said, is there a closed form for $n$ doors where $n \le 60$.

Comment: Let $a(n)=0$ if $a$ is odd, $a(n)=1$ if $n$ is twice an odd number, and $2$ if $n$ is divisible by $4$.
Let $b(n)=0$ if $n$ is not divisible by $3$, and let $b(n)=1$ if $n$ is divisible by $3$.
Let $c(n)=0$ if $n$ is not divisible by $5$, and $1$ if it is.
Calculate $(-1)^{a(n)+b(n)+c(n)}$. If this is $1$, Door $n$ ends up open.

Comment: If $1\le n\le60$, then door $n$ will be open at the end of the process if and only if$$2\mid n,\ 3\mid n,\ 4\not\mid n,\ 5\not\mid n$$or$$4\mid n,\ 3\not\mid n,\ 5\not\mid n$$or any of four other similar conditions.  I'm afraid you are unlikely to get a simple answer without brute force, though "careful" brute force as in @AndréNicolas's comment will certainly beat "mindless" brute force.

Comment: I basically came up with door $n$ is open iff exactly zero, two or all of these were true: $2 \mid n, 3 \mid n, 4 \mid n, 5 \mid n$. On another note, I'm pretty excited LaTeX is allowed here. I wish this site was around when I was in school...

Comment: That's correct, but you have to recognise that the four conditions are not independent.  For example it is impossible to have $4\mid n$, $5\mid n$ true and $2\mid n$, $3\mid n$ false.

Comment: Fantastic, I'm just happy there wasn't a simple formula I was overlooking. Thanks David and @AndréNicolas for your comments.

Comment: Not a problem!  BTW I just added an extra bit to my answer regarding your palindromic sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The following closed form is a reformulation of the algorithm:

$$
\big(1 + sgn(n \mod 2) + sgn(n \mod 3) + sgn(n \mod 4) + sgn(n \mod 5)\big) \mod 2
$$

This can also be expressed as the sum rotating roots of 1:

$$
\big(\sum_{i = 1}^{5}\frac{1}{i}\sum_{j = 1}^{i}e^{\frac{2j\pi}{i}}\big) \mod 2
$$

The sum may collapse further, thanks to the modulus. I did not check.